# Is there a more concise way to say that calculations are within the data errors of experimental measurements?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

It seems that "theoretical calculations are within the data errors of experimental measurements" is a rather wordy way to express a rather simple concept, and I am wondering if there is a more concise and professional way to phrase that.

Comment: "Compatible with experiments"

Comment: there are statistical tools meant to measure things like correlations between theory and experiment. usually, a statement like that would be worded something like "the theory accounts for 89% of the variation in the data, to a confidence level of 99%".